# What causes IndexError: tuple index out of range in py2exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

I've just installed Python 3.8.5 and py2exe 0.9.2.2.  I have a setup.py that works with py2exe 0.6.9 on Python 2.7.  When I run
`setup.py py2exe` (the actual command line is
`py setupexe.py py2exe`)
with the new version I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setupexe.py", line 4, in <module>
        setup(name='md2html',
      File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
        self._run()
      File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
        builder.analyze()
      File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 160, in analyze
        self.mf.import_hook(modname)
      File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 388, in _scan_code
        for what, args in self._scan_opcodes(code):
      File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 417, in _scan_opcodes
        yield "store", (names[oparg],)
    IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from md2html import __VERSION__
setup(name='md2html',
      version=__VERSION__,
      author='xxxxx',
      author_email='xxxxx',
      description='Convert Markdown to HTML',
      requires=['markdown(>=2.6.6)'],
      console=['md2html.py'],
      options={"py2exe":{
          "excludes": [
              'pyreadline', 'difflib', 'doctest', 'optparse', 'pickle', 'calendar', 'email', 'ftplib', 'httplib', 'rfc822', 'socket', 'select', 'ssl', '_ssl']  # Exclude standard library
               }}
)
```

As I said, this worked before.  My next step would be to run it in pdb, but before I jump into unfamiliar code, I thought I'd ask.  Running on Windows 10.
Thanks.
Update: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059111/error-while-trying-to-compile-python-script-to-exe) produces a similar error.  The answer is that py2exe doesn't work with versions after Python 3.4.  Disappointing!  It suggests [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which I will investigate.  I really hope there's a way to make py2exe work.

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question to format the traceback as code. Thanks!